# Android Terminal-IDE: terminal-gcc error: arm-eabi-gcc not found

Tags: android, gcc, ide, terminal-ide

I'm using [Terminal-IDE](http://Terminal-IDE.com/) as my development environment. ([Google code site here.](http://code.google.com/p/terminal-ide/))

I'm running Terminal-IDE v 2.02 - the very latest. My Android versions are:

- Android 4.0.3
- Software version 2.14.531.3 71ORD
- (the rest aren't likely pertinent, but more on request)

I'm in a suitable development directory with a simple enough c source code file ready and run 'make'.

I have never yet gotten any compilation to work successfully. Most likely, there's a version mis-match with regard to what executable is available versus what the software is looking for.

Here's the command and error message:

```
terminal-gcc -c -Wall -I/data/data/com.spartacusrex.spartacuside/files/local/include tester.c -o tester.o
/data/data/com.spartacusrex.spartacuside/files/system/bin/terminal-gcc[43]: arm-eabi-gcc: not found
make: *** [tester.o] Error 127
```

Snafu, of course. I'm not at all sure how to find out what the right compiler file name(s) should be because, on this non-rooted phone, I don't have permissions to hunt through the PATH and find the actual executables.

It may also be that PATH is set wrong. All input appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

...I'm not sure what's supposed to happen, but I found in the Terminal-IDE directory tree the file:

```
$IDESYSTEM/android-gcc-4.4.0.tar.gz
```

I also found that **terminal-gcc** is a bash script. Looking inside it seemed to say that a gcc tree should exist in **"$HOME"**, which is the installation directory. So, I unzipped, then un-tarred the file identified above and put the resulting directory tree as a top-level subdirectory.

Well well, what do you know? Success.

I went a little further and created soft links to the actual compiler in ~/bin for both **gcc** and just **cc**, and suddenly all my previously created **"Makefile"** scripts used in other projects I wanted to move over started working perfectly.

Apparently, even though I thought I'd done it right, I overlooked running this script:

```
./system/bin/install_gcc
```

It extracts the tar, like I did, but does not create the links you may need.

Hey, if you're glad I got here before you, give it a thumbs up!

Answer (score 2):

A credit goes to @Richard T for his enthusiasm regarding *Terminal IDE*. The answer is intended to enumerate the steps needed for running a C code.

### **To run a C code**

1. Run *Terminal IDE* and extract the *gcc* package by executing

   **install_gcc**
2. Create a directory for your projects within the *Terminal IDE* directory tree. Then in the directory create a source *.c* file with some code (*filename.c* here). Compile it

   **terminal-gcc -c filename.c**
3. Create the executable file

   **terminal-gcc filename.o -o filename.out**
4. Run the output file

   **./filename.out**

---

If you'd like to use the PC (laptop) keyboard you can telnet *Terminal IDE*.

### **To Telnet Terminal IDE**

1. From *Terminal IDE* start the *telnetd* deamon by executing

   **telnetd**
2. Connect the *Android* device to the PC (laptop) and type

   **adb forward tcp:[port] tcp:8080**

   **telnet 127.0.0.1 [port]**

P.S. *Telnet's* default port is 23.

Comment: If you're like me, you're LOATH to _ever_ use telnet! Instead, I use ssh. There are pretty good directions for setting it up on the TerminalIDE web site - don't recall which one. You can try TerminalIDE.org, I think, and it links to the others.